# Can multiple classes have RequestMapping("/") if their method RequestMappings don't conflict?

Tags: spring, request-mapping

If you have two classes, both with "" (nothing) mapped to the class level, and there are several @RequestMapping annotated methods in each, but none of the methods' mappings conflict with each other, will it work?  If not, how could you achieve the desired result with two controllers?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping()
public class Controller1 {

   @RequestMapping("pageA")
   public void someMethodA() {
       // do something later
   }

   @RequestMapping("pageC")
   public void someMethodC() {
       // do something later
   }

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping()
public class Controller2 {

   @RequestMapping("pageB")
   public void someMethodB() {
       // do something later
   }

   @RequestMapping("pageE")
   public void someMethodE() {
           // do something later
       }

}
```

Comment: what is stopping you from trying it out yourself and see

Answer (score 3):

> If you have two classes, both with "" (nothing) mapped to the class
>   level, and there are several @RequestMapping annotated methods in
>   each, but none of the methods' mappings conflict with each other, will
>   it work?

Yes it will work.

If you want same url pattern for all your endpoint (let's just say @RequestMapping(path = "/item-service/v1") ) another option is to add that as a context path instead of adding it to every Controller.